# How to substract some hours from a date with MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM format?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to ask you how to subtract 6 hours from a date in Microsoft Access. For example if it's `13/10/2015 14:20`, then the new date should be `13/10/2015 08:20`, if it's `13/10/2015 04:00`, then it should be `12/10/2015 22:00`. I just made a new row, and I wrote

```
[new date]=[minuen date]-[06:00]
```

But it throws:

> bad syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to go 6 hours previous.

```
=DateAdd("h", -6, [minuen date])
```